# Where is the Metadata Page on Google Compute Engine for Creating sshkeys

Tags: ssh-keys, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

In [the documentation describing](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/console#sshkeys) setting up sshkeys on google compute engine (depicted below), the instructions say to "Click on the Metadata page" and enter your sshKeys.  Where is this metadata page?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the Google Developers Console (https://console.developers.google.com).
2. Click on your project.
3. Click on **Compute Engine** on the left menu.
4. Click on **Metadata**, which is the 6th item down on the expanded menu beneath where you clicked on **Compute Engine**.